# What is the "Good Karma" Choice - Saving Trish or the Doctors?

Tags: infamous

During the final chapter of the game you have to choose between saving Trish or saving doctors from one of two buildings. The game claims you have enough time only for one or the other. It also presents a karma choice moment.

It seems that both choices are technically *good*. I'd think the evil choice would be to have a beer and let both the doctors and Trish dangle to their deaths.

If I'm trying to maintain **good karma** as far as the plot is concerned, which choice should I make?

Comment: This is a "needs of the many" vs "needs of the few" moment - saving your girl is the bad karma choice :)

Comment: @agent86 Thanks. BTW I'm still new here and not sure how to hide some of the detail as a *spoiler*. Although the title itself is kind of a giveaway...

Comment: Spoiler text is covered [in this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers/71396#71396).  I always forget the markdown for it though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the doctors, that will be the "good karma" choice.

I do recommend you try this mission again with the bad karma choice, not spoiling too much, I would say the bad karma choice is one of the better scenes in the game.

Comment: @yuck: infamous is one of the best games I've ever played, I would also recommend a second playthrough making every choice differently than the previous, the results are at times extremely interesting.